# Object initializer for attributes?

Tags: .net, attributes

I have the following attribute in which I pass types to the constructor:

```
[DataTypeConversion(typeof(StringToBoolConverter), typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter))]
```

However, I'd really like to ditch the constructor and force the object setup through an initializer like so:

```
[DataTypeConversion{InConverterType = typeof(StringToBoolConverter), OutConverterType = typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter)}]
```

It doesn't appear that I can do this, though.  Is there another way or is it simply not supported with attributes?

**Edit:** Why do I want to do this?  It's not just improve readability, but it will also force the developer to specify a property.  While attributes support named constructor arguments, they're optional.

**Edit2:** I can instantiate an attribute like this:

```
var attr = new DataTypeConversionAttribute
{
    InConverterType = typeof(StringToBoolConverter),
    OutConverterType = typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter)
};
```

I want to be able to instantiate it the same way when decorating a property.

**Update**

astef provided the correct answer.  Here's my attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DataTypeConversionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type InConverterType { get; set; }

    public Type OutConverterType { get; set; }
}
```

While `{}` are used for object initializers in standard code, you need to use `()` for attributes like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DataTypeConversion(InConverterType = typeof(StringToBoolConverter), OutConverterType = typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter))]
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: add read-write-properties to your `DataTypeConversionAttribute` and use it as `[DataTypeConversion(InConverter = typeof(StringToBoolConverter), OutConverter = typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter))]`

Comment: Ctor arguments (positional arguments) are not optional, properties (named arguments) are optional. Both of them are set inside brackets: `[DataTypeConversion(ctorPosArg1, ctorPosArg2, PropertyA = arg3, PropertyB = arg4)]`

Comment: @astef Correct, the arguments themselves are required.  I was saying that named arguments are optional.  Also, they're not inside brackets, but parentheses.  Curly braces are what's used for object initializers which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't get this question. You want to be able to replace the parenthesis usage with curly brackets? Why? Why isn't `[DataTypeConversionAttribute(InConverterType = ..., OutConverterType = ...)]` good enough? Why do you need to use `{...}` instead of `(...)` ?

Comment: Attributes don't have optional parameters out of the box. Only if you specifically make the parameters optional are they optional.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't want to replace parentheses with curly braces.  I was just specifying curly braces so everyone would know that I am trying to set public properties through an object initializer.  Curly braces are the only way to do this.  What was throwing me off was that attributes do not use curly braces when used to decorate a class member.  astef has provided the answer that addresses my inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
[DataTypeConversion(InConverter = typeof(StringToBoolConverter), OutConverter = typeof(BoolToYesNoConverter))]
```

(brackets instead of braces)

I assume that `DataTypeConversionAttribute` has a default constructor and two public properties with public setters: `InConverter` and `OutConverter` with return type `System.Type`

Comment: I deleted my comment because your answer *is* the right way to do it.  I was looking for curly braces, but it seems that those are not supported with attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by the C#-Compiler for declaring Attributes on types using this style. Take [a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx) at the MSDN how to use attributes.